# Interface callback between fragments for android's navigation architecture library (nav_graph)

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

So when I was using a frameLayout to swap fragments with fragment manager i could do something like this to send arguments to the new pushed fragment

```
class TestFragment : GenericFragment(R.layout.test_fragment) {

    private var arg1: Int = 0
    private lateinit var onResult : ( () -> Unit )

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(arg1 : Int, onResult: ( () -> Unit )) = TestFragment().apply {
            this.arg1 = arg1
            this.onResult = onResult
        }
    }
}

frag = TestFragment.newInstance(1) {
    //some stuff to do when finished
}

val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(content.id, frag, tag)
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

The question is how do I do this with the arch navigation components (**android.arch.navigation:navigation**). I found that you could only send primitive types or some types of Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

One method to do this would be to use a Shared View Model in combination with Live data between these 2 fragments.

```
sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this.getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Another option would be to use FragmentManager.BackStackEntry
I haven't tried this one. You can find more here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry

Comment: I really don't like that all the answers I find mention a shared view model. It doesn't work as well with a modularized app or an SDK. For example, if I wanted to create a generic Fragment as part of an SDK, then let the integrator show the Fragment via navigation, then let them decide what action to take when a button in that Fragment is tapped via a callback. 
I really wish Android would just let us pass a function into the navigation bundle.